# Python objects and JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a python object which I dump to json and write to a file.

```
results = [
{'destination': (x,y), 'id': 'dsss', 'origin': (x,r), 'waypoints': [[s,l],[d,s]]},
{'destination': (x1, y1), 'id': 'ddsdsee', 'origin': (z,f), 'waypoints': [[e,y],[d,e]]}]

with gzip.open("test.json.gz",'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(results,outfile,indent=2)
```

I then open the file elsewhere, via:

```
schedule_f = gzip.open("test.json.gz")
schedule = json.load(schedule_f)
```

`pprint(schedule[0])` return:

```
{'destination': [x,y], 'id': 'dsss', 'origin': [x,r], 'waypoints': [[s,l],[d,s]]
```

Why are `origin` and `destination` fields converted to a list? I clearly specified `(` and not `[`

Comment: Your input is not valid Python, the first item in `results` is missing a closing `}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON doesn't have any concept of tuples: only arrays, which map to Python lists.

There is no difference from a practical point of view, but if you think you really really need tuples, you will have to convert them yourself

Answer (score 1):

Nested Python objects can be complexer than you are are allowed to store in JSON format. JSON format does only have a container and its parsed as list when you import it into Python.

Such format conversion are not conservative, they destroy informations. You will not be able to store `datetime` too, it will be casted to string.

Answer (score 1):

JSON does not support tuples, so the `json` module converts them to arrays, which *are* supported by JSON.

Answer (score 1):

JSON does not know the "(" (it is not specified in the JSON notation).

Your `json.dump` *intelligently* converts it to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Please, read what JSON is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

JSON doesn't support tuple datatype. It supports list only, that's why Python tuples were converted into JSON lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the dump and load object exactly same then use `pickle` module instead of `json` module.